# Get automatic response from Server

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, tomcat, servlet-3.0

In my application i need to get any response to the jsp page automatically without any user action occur. How can i get that type of response like print some text to the jsp or invoke any function of the jquery from the server. Im using apache-tomcat7.0.42 and struts2 spring3 framework.

Comment: At what basis you want it to get that response? Are you looking for ajax kind of solution? need some more demonstration...

Comment: i need ajax kind of response for my page, that response should come once for every 10 mins like that.

Comment: okay! then what have you tried with ajax kind of stuff, plz post some code to lookup. such little info is not enough to answer it.

Comment: i need to tell the user as within some minutes ur session will timed out so i tried script timeout and timer function, that may arise some error. so i need some trigger from server side to invoke my script.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need [meta tag refresh](http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv_refresh)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=urlToFetchData">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below or you can use meta tag refresh

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Refresh Header Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Auto Refresh Header Example</h2>
<%
   // Set refresh, autoload time as 5 seconds
   response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);
   // Get current time
   Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
   String am_pm;
   int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
   int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
   if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
      am_pm = "AM";
   else
      am_pm = "PM";
   String CT = hour+":"+ minute +":"+ second +" "+ am_pm;
   out.println("Crrent Time: " + CT + "\n");
%>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need without refresh my page